# Remove permissions from role

Tags: javascript, permissions, discord.js

I want to do a command that removes a specific permission from all the roles on the servers. So if I do `+pkick` it searches for all the roles with kick permissions and removes it from them. I read the docs, but it doesn't mention it.

Comment: This is not a good idea, since it's API spam. I recommend *at least* putting a delay between each update

Answer (score 0):

you have to loop through all the roles and then update the permissions.

```
message.guild.roles.forEach(role => {
    const rolePermissions = role.permissions.toArray();
    rolePermissions = rolePermissions.filter(e => e !== 'KICK_MEMBERS');
    role.setPermissions(rolePermissions);
});
```